# html.erb - How to fill last row with empty divs

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view in my rails app that is an image gallery.  The view looks like this:

view.html.erb

```
  <div class="photo-row">
    <% @item.item_images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
      <% if (index % 3 == 0) && (index != 0) %>
        </div><div class="photo-row">
      <% end %>           
      <div class="photo-wrapper">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<%= image.picture.large.url %>"><img class="pending-photo" src="<%= image.picture.small.url %>" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

As you can see the row will fill up with three images and then create a new row.  For my alignment I need the last non-full row to be filled with with 3 `photo-wrapper` divs.  For example if an `@item` has 7 `item_images` I need there to be three rows.  The first two are full and the last should have 1 with the image and 2 empty wrappers.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the [`in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) helper. It splits your array in groups of a given size. Missing elements are filled with `nil` by default.

Something like this should work:

```
<% @item.item_images.in_groups_of(3) do |images| %>
  <div class="photo-row">
    <% images.each do |image| %>
      <div class="photo-wrapper">
        <% if image %>
          <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<%= image.picture.large.url %>"><img class="pending-photo" src="<%= image.picture.small.url %>" alt="" /></a>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You could also use the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helpers instead of `<a>` and `<img>` Tags. Maybe wrapped in a custom helper:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def fancybox(image)
  link_to image.picture.large.url, class: 'fancybox', rel: 'group') do
    image_tag(image.picture.small.url, alt: '', class: 'pending-photo')
  end
end
```

and in your view:

```
<% @item.item_images.in_groups_of(3) do |images| %>
  <div class="photo-row">
    <% images.each do |image| %>
      <div class="photo-wrapper">
        <%= fancybox(image) if image %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[Note that I haven't tested this code, it could contain errors]

Comment: Beat me to it. It would be nice if you showed them a solution including the `link_to` and `image_tag` helpers

Comment: didn't know about that method, sweet!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `modulo` operator to achieve that. In your example, `7 % 3` would return `1` (`7 == 2*3 + 1`). So `3 - (@item.item_images.length % 3)` is the number you are looking for:

```
<% if @item.item_images.length % 3 != 0 %>
    <% (3 - (@item.item_images.length % 3)).times do %>
        <div class="photo-wrapper"></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try achieve this with if statement. Just check for the last item.

Something like this:

```
<% @item.item_images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
  <% if image == @item.last %>
    do something
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or check @item length

```
<% if (index + 1) == @stuff.length %>
  do something
<% end %>
```